# OpenCV. How to extract numbers from mask to array

Tags: c++, opencv

I try read numbers from image and built mask of picture for this.
But how I should extract drawn numbers to something like `std::vector<int>`

[image]

```
void find_numbers(const cv::Mat& image){

    cv::Mat cropped_image = image(FIXED_POINTS::cropped_statusbar.first, FIXED_POINTS::cropped_statusbar.second);
  
    cv::Mat resized_crop;
    cv::resize(cropped_image, resized_crop, cropped_image.size()*4, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    
    cv::Mat colored{resized_crop};
    cv::cvtColor(resized_crop,colored, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    cv::Mat msk{resized_crop};
    
    cv::inRange(colored, cv::Scalar{0, 0, 140}, cv::Scalar{170, 255, 255},msk);
    auto krn = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, {5, 3});
    cv::Mat dlt{msk};
    cv::dilate(msk, dlt, krn);
    cv::Mat dst{dlt};
    cv::bitwise_and(dlt,dlt, dst, msk);   
}
```

Comment: AFAIK OpenCV doesn't support OCR. You need another library for this, e.g. [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), or write your own OCR logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jabaa from comments.
Tesseract solved it.

```
void find_numbers(const cv::Mat& image){

    cv::Mat cropped_image = image(FIXED_POINTS::cropped_statusbar.first, FIXED_POINTS::cropped_statusbar.second);
  
    cv::Mat resized_crop;
    cv::resize(cropped_image, resized_crop, cropped_image.size()*4, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
    
    cv::Mat colored{resized_crop};
    cv::cvtColor(resized_crop,colored, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    cv::Mat msk{resized_crop};
    
    cv::inRange(colored, cv::Scalar{0, 0, 140}, cv::Scalar{145, 255, 255},msk);
    auto krn = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, {5, 3});
    cv::Mat dlt{msk};
    cv::dilate(msk, dlt, krn);
    cv::Mat dst{dlt};
    cv::bitwise_and(dlt,dlt, dst, msk);
    cv::imwrite("out.jpeg", dst);
   
    auto api = std::make_unique<tesseract::TessBaseAPI>();
    api->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
    api->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_RAW_LINE);
    api->SetImage(dst.data, dst.cols, dst.rows,  4, 4*dst.cols);
    std::cout << std::string(api->GetUTF8Text()) << std::endl;
    api->End();    
}
```